# Simulating Rics-v verilog

Tags: verilog, simulation, riscv

I have compiled my benchmark and generated the .hex file.
where to include the .hex file in the verilog files.

all what I have for the verilog files are Top.DefaultVLSIConfig.v and memdessertMemDessert.DeafultVLSIConfig.v inside rocket-chip folder

I don't have vcs simulator in my os, can I take the verilog file and the hex file and do the simulation in another platform?

Haider

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use another platform. On any platform you use, you will need a verilog simulator. Rocket Chip includes the verilog harness to use vcs, so if you use another simulator you may need to change the harness.

I would recommend using the [C++ emulator Rocket Chip provides](https://github.com/ucb-bar/rocket-chip#emulator).

Answer (score 0):

> I don't have vcs simulator in my os

You can run your code using vcs simulator 2014.12 in [EDAplayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/)

Comment: But risc-v verilog simulator is needed to be installed

Comment: where is the rtl code of risc-v that you want to simulate?

Answer (score 0):

this isn't really a verilog question, it's a design dependent question, and partly a tool question.

there must be some memory definition somewhere in the code where you have to put a file reference to your hex file. should be pretty simple to find it.